# Setting up public key encryption for git ssh

Tags: git, version-control, github, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys

I want to to setup public key access to my git shell application (windowspowershell v1.0). It's the shell application that comes with the [github for windows](http://windows.github.com/) application.

I want to push commits to a bare repository on my remote CentOS web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put your keypair in `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/`, and upload your public key to server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I tried that and I know how to do it, but I get a refused access error.